# How can I make the required roles either or instead of both

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm setting up my commands and doing finishing touches meaning which roles are gonna have access to which commands, and I've ran into an issue where I want 2 roles to have access to the same command but I'm unsure how to do this OR that, I've tried a few different ways but it only lets me do either 1 or both of them at the same time.

this is how it looks in action meaning within the code itself

```
{
    permissions: [],
    requiredRoles: ['Staff', 'Rose'],
}
```

and this is how it looks behind the scenes in my command handler

```
for (const requiredRole of requiredRoles) {
    const role = guild.roles.cache.find(
        (role) => role.name === requiredRole
    )

    if (!role || !member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
        message.reply(
            `You must have the "${requiredRole}" role to use this command.`
        )
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collection#hasAny()` or `Collection#hasAll()`

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.hasAny(requiredRoles)) // member has none of those roles
```

or

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.hasAll(requiredRoles)) // member does not have ALL of these roles
```

Comment: doesnt work sadly